# Emmeans continuous independant variable

Tags: r, plot, glm, emmeans

I want to explan `Type_f` with  `Type_space`  of the experiment and the rate of `Exhaustion_product` and quantitative variable  `Age`.

Here is my data :

```
res=structure(list(Type_space = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("", 
    "29-v1", "29-v2", "88-v1", "88-v2"), class = "factor"), Id = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
    42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
    55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
    68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
    81L, 82L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
    26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
    39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
    52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
    65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
    78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 
    91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 
    103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 
    114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 
    125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 
    136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 
    147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 
    158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
    42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
    55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
    68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
    81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
    94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
    30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
    43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
    56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
    69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 
    82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 
    95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
    106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
    117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
    128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
    139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 
    150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 
    161L, 162L, 163L, 164L), Age = c(3, 10, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 8, 2, 
    13, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 8, 3, 6, 1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
    5, 4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 8, 2, 3, 4, 7, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 1, 
    4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 8, 7, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 10, 
    7, 5, 3, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 6, 1, 12, 1, 6, 3, 4, 
    4, 13, 5, 2, 7, 7, 20, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 4, 3, 8, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 
    2, 3, 2, 2, 6, 11, 2, 5, 5, 9, 4, 4, 2, 7, 2, 7, 10, 6, 9, 2, 
    2, 5, 11, 1, 8, 8, 4, 1, 2, 14, 11, 13, 20, 3, 3, 4, 16, 2, 6, 
    11, 9, 11, 4, 5, 6, 19, 5, 2, 6, 1, 7, 11, 3, 9, 2, 3, 6, 20, 
    8, 6, 2, 11, 18, 9, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 8, 3, 5, 6, 2, 5, 8, 11, 4, 
    9, 7, 2, 12, 8, 2, 9, 5, 4, 15, 5, 13, 5, 10, 13, 7, 6, 1, 12, 
    12, 10, 4, 2, 16, 7, 17, 11, 18, 4, 3, 12, 1, 3, 7, 3, 6, 5, 
    11, 10, 12, 6, 14, 8, 6, 7, 8, 5, 10, 12, 6, 13, 3, 11, 14, 7, 
    9, 9, 4, 13, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 7, 9, 3, 10, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 
    2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 13, 4, 1, 3, 1, 11, 4, 1, 3, 3, 7, 5, 4, 5, 6, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 7, 6, 9, 5, 1, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 8, 8, 3, 2, 
    2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 8, 11, 1, 6, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 4, 2, 7, 3, 
    3, 1, 3, 9, 5, 2, 4, 12, 1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 6, 1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 7, 
    3, 5, 5, 3, 7, 1, 5, 2, 1, 15, 3, 5, 2, 5, 13, 6, 2, 3, 5, 2, 
    8, 4, 2, 6, 7, 2, 4, 1, 13, 8, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 11, 
    4, 1, 7, 7, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4, 10, 1, 2, 6, 1, 11, 3, 8, 9, 2, 6, 
    8, 11, 14, 16, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 10, 4, 9, 3, 12, 8, 11, 8, 8, 5, 
    1, 4, 13, 3, 8, 5, 14, 3, 5, 5, 12, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 6, 9, 6, 
    10, 5, 2, 3, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1, 14, 3, 5, 9, 6, 2, 2, 
    2, 4, 4, 11, 14, 2, 2, 2, 8, 7, 2, 10, 12, 1, 6, 10, 2, 3, 5, 
    10, 6, 1, 8, 4, 11, 5, 4, 3, 6, 2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 9, 11, 7, 3, 15, 
    3, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 9, 13, 8, 5, 7, 8, 8, 5, 10), Type_product = c("f", 
    "s", "f", "f", "f", "f", "s", "c", "s", "f", "c", "f", "f", "f", 
    "s", "s", "f", "f", "c", "f", "s", "f", "f", "s", "f", "c", "f", 
    "f", "s", "f", "f", "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "c", 
    "c", "c", "f", "f", "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "s", 
    "f", "c", "c", "c", "s", "f", "c", "f", "f", "c", "c", "f", "c", 
    "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", 
    "c", "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "s", "f", "c", "f", "f", "f", "c", 
    "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "s", "c", "c", "f", "f", "c", "c", "f", 
    "f", "c", "c", "f", "f", "s", "f", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", "c", 
    "f", "f", "f", "c", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "c", "f", "f", 
    "f", "f", "c", "s", "f", "c", "f", "f", "c", "f", "f", "f", "c", 
    "f", "c", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", "f", "c", "c", "c", "f", "f", 
    "c", "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "c", "c", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", 
    "c", "c", "c", "f", "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "f", "c", "f", "c", 
    "c", "c", "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "f", 
    "f", "f", "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", "c", 
    "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "c", 
    "c", "f", "c", "f", "c", "f", "c", "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", "c", 
    "c", "c", "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", "f", "f", "c", 
    "f", "f", "s", "c", "s", "c", "f", "c", "c", "s", "c", "c", "s", 
    "c", "m", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "s", "f", "f", 
    "c", "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "f", "c", "f", "f", "f", "s", "f", 
    "f", "c", "f", "c", "f", "m", "c", "c", "c", "f", "s", "f", "f", 
    "f", "c", "s", "c", "m", "f", "c", "m", "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", 
    "f", "c", "m", "f", "c", "c", "f", "c", "f", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
    "c", "f", "f", "f", "c", "m", "f", "m", "m", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
    "m", "m", "c", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", 
    "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", "f", "c", "f", "m", "f", "f", "f", "c", 
    "f", "f", "f", "c", "f", "f", "c", "c", "f", "c", "f", "c", "m", 
    "f", "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "f", "f", "c", "c", "f", "f", "c", 
    "c", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "c", "f", "c", "c", "f", "c", 
    "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "f", "c", "f", "c", "f", "c", "f", 
    "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "f", "f", "f", 
    "c", "f", "c", "f", "f", "c", "c", "f", "f", "c", "f", "c", "f", 
    "c", "c", "c", "f", "f", "c", "f", "c", "c", "f", "c", "f", "c", 
    "f", "c", "f", "c", "m", "c", "c", "m", "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", 
    "f", "c", "c", "c", "f", "c", "c", "m", "c", "m", "m", "c", "c", 
    "f", "c", "c", "c", "c", "m", "c", "c", "c", "m", "m", "m", "c", 
    "c", "c", "c", "m", "m", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", 
    "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m"), Exhaustion_product = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L), .Label = c("(0,10]", "(10,20]", "(20,30]", "(30,40]", "(40,50]", 
    "(50,60]", "(60,70]", "(70,80]", "(80,90]", "(90,100]"), class = "factor"), 
        Type_f = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
        1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
        1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
        1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
        1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
        1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
        0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
        1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
        0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
        0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
        1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
        0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Type_space", "Id", "Age", 
    "Type_product", "Exhaustion_product", "Type_f"), row.names = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
    42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
    55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
    68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 73L, 75L, 76L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 85L, 
    86L, 91L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 
    111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 
    122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 
    133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 
    144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 
    155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 
    166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 
    177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 
    188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 
    201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 212L, 213L, 
    214L, 215L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 225L, 227L, 
    229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 
    242L, 243L, 244L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 253L, 254L, 
    256L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 269L, 270L, 
    272L, 273L, 274L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 
    284L, 285L, 287L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 
    297L, 298L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 306L, 308L, 309L, 311L, 312L, 
    313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 322L, 323L, 325L, 
    326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 331L, 332L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 338L, 339L, 
    340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 
    352L, 353L, 354L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 363L, 364L, 
    365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 
    377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 384L, 385L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 
    391L, 393L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 
    404L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 
    418L, 419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 
    429L, 430L, 431L, 432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 
    440L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 
    452L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 
    463L, 464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 
    474L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 486L, 
    487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 
    498L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 509L, 
    510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 519L, 520L, 
    521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 531L, 
    532L, 534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 541L, 542L, 543L, 
    547L, 548L, 550L, 551L, 552L, 553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 558L, 
    559L, 560L, 561L, 562L, 563L, 565L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 570L, 
    571L, 572L, 573L, 575L, 577L, 579L, 580L, 581L, 582L, 583L, 585L, 
    586L, 587L, 590L, 592L, 599L, 606L, 608L), class = "data.frame")

    an=Anova(glm(Type_f ~  Type_space  + Exhaustion_product + Age , family=binomial,data=res))
    gl=glm(Type_f ~  Type_space  + Exhaustion_product + Age  , family=binomial,data=res)
    library("emmeans")
    emmp <- emmeans( gl, pairwise ~ Exhaustion_product + Age)
    summary( emmp, infer=TRUE)
```

(1) In the case of categorical variable the results are clear. But in the case of Age which is significant in the GLM, what is the value generated in the `emmeans` ?`5.455426`.Is that is means ? How can I interpret this ?

```
 (0,10]             5.455426  0.36901411 0.2935894 Inf -0.20641061  0.94443883   1.257  0.2088
```

(2)I want to generate graphic representationof the interaction `age` and `Exhaustion_product`. Also this do not make sens.

```
emmip(gl, Exhaustion_product ~ Age)
```

Edit 1
    Contrast result

```
$contrasts
 contrast                                                estimate        SE  df   asymp.LCL asymp.UCL z.ratio p.value
 (0,10],5.45542635658915 - (10,20],5.45542635658915    0.33231353 0.4078967 Inf -0.95814279 1.6227698   0.815  0.9984
 (0,10],5.45542635658915 - (20,30],5.45542635658915   -0.53694399 0.4194460 Inf -1.86393835 0.7900504  -1.280  0.9582
 (0,10],5.45542635658915 - (30,40],5.45542635658915   -0.16100309 0.4139472 Inf -1.47060101 1.1485948  -0.389  1.0000
 (0,10],5.45542635658915 - (40,50],5.45542635658915    0.40113723 0.4021403 Inf -0.87110757 1.6733820   0.998  0.9925
 (0,10],5.45542635658915 - (50,60],5.45542635658915    0.60576562 0.4106536 Inf -0.69341247 1.9049437   1.475  0.9022
 (0,10],5.45542635658915 - (60,70],5.45542635658915    1.38800301 0.4319258 Inf  0.02152631 2.7544797   3.214  0.0430
 (0,10],5.45542635658915 - (70,80],5.45542635658915    1.01677522 0.4147441 Inf -0.29534399 2.3288944   2.452  0.2952
 (0,10],5.45542635658915 - (80,90],5.45542635658915    1.99085692 0.4747929 Inf  0.48876247 3.4929514   4.193  0.0011
 (0,10],5.45542635658915 - (90,100],5.45542635658915   2.03923289 0.4745872 Inf  0.53778910 3.5406767   4.297  0.0007
```

Comment: That is the mean age. You can specify a particular set of ages, or use `cov.reduce = range` to evaluate at the min and max see `vignette(“basics”, “emmeans”)` and perhaps some of the other vignettes.

Comment: Ok this is the mean, In my example (20;30] this would say that this for interval and this mean of age, we  have significant p-value with positive slope. This mean that 'Type_f' is grwing with this interval ang mean age. But what about to have above or below this mean ?
ref_grid(gl, cov.reduce = range) returns tomein fact min and maw,but how to use it ? Thanks

Comment: Why did you edit the question? Now it shows output that you could not have observed and an emmip call that won’t run. So the question no longer even makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for that! It was only for the significant p-value.I put the original code

Comment: On your earlier comment, you have exactly the same slope at every age and every level of the factor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because this question seems like a self-learning one, I am going to do a similar example, not the same data. But the structure is the same, with one factor and one covariate as predictors.

The example is the `emmeans::fiber` dataset. Its response variable is fiber strength, the continuous predictor is the diameter, and the factor is the machine it was made on.

Model:

```
> mod = glm(log(strength) ~ machine + diameter, data = fiber)
> summary(mod)
... (output has been abbreviated) ...
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  3.124387   0.068374  45.695 6.74e-14
machineB     0.026025   0.023388   1.113    0.290
machineC    -0.044593   0.025564  -1.744    0.109
diameter     0.023557   0.002633   8.946 2.22e-06

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.001356412)
```

Analysis with emmeans is based on the reference grid, which by default consists of all levels of the factor and the mean of the covariate:

```
> ref_grid(mod)
'emmGrid' object with variables:
    machine = A, B, C
    diameter = 24.133
Transformation: “log”
```

You can confirm in R that `mean(fiber$diameter)` is 24.133. I emphasize this is the mean of the *diameter* values, not of anything in the model.

```
> summary(.Last.value)
 machine diameter prediction         SE  df
 A       24.13333   3.692901 0.01670845 Inf
 B       24.13333   3.718925 0.01718853 Inf
 C       24.13333   3.648307 0.01819206 Inf

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
```

Those summary values are the predictions from `mod` at each combination of `machine` and `diameter`. Now look at EMMs for `machine`

```
> emmeans(mod, "machine")
 machine   emmean         SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 A       3.692901 0.01670845 Inf  3.660153  3.725649
 B       3.718925 0.01718853 Inf  3.685237  3.752614
 C       3.648307 0.01819206 Inf  3.612652  3.683963

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

... we get exactly the same three predictions. But if we look at `diameter`:

```
> emmeans(mod, "diameter")
 diameter   emmean          SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 24.13333 3.686711 0.009509334 Inf  3.668073  3.705349

Results are averaged over the levels of: machine 
Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

... we get the EMM is equal to the average of the three predicted values in the reference grid. And note that it says in the annotations that results were averaged over `machine`, so it is worth reading that.

To get a graphical representation of the model results, we can do

```
> emmip(mod, machine ~ diameter, cov.reduce = range)
```

[image: results of emmip()]

The argument `cov.reduce = range` is added to cause the reference grid to use the min and max diameter, rather than its average. Without that, we'd have gotten three dots instead of three lines. This plot still shows the model predictions, just over a more detailed grid of values. Notice that all three lines have the same slope. That is vbecause the model was specified that way: the `diameter` effect is *added* to the `machine` effect. Each line thus has the common slope of 0.023557 (see the output from `summary(mod)`.

There is no *post hoc* test needed for `diameter`, since its *one* effect is already tested in `summary(mod)`.

One last thing. The model used `log(strength)` as the response. If we want the EMMs on the same scale as `strength`, just add `type = "response"`:

```
> emmeans(mod, "machine", type = "response")
 machine response        SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 A       40.16118 0.6710311 Inf  38.86728  41.49815
 B       41.22008 0.7085126 Inf  39.85455  42.63239
 C       38.40960 0.6987496 Inf  37.06421  39.80384

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

Again, the annotations below the results help explain the output.

Comment: Thank your very much for his extended response. In the summary(mod) we explore whether 'strength' could be explained by 'diameter'. estimate is positive and p-value is significant, so we can conclude tht 'diameter' growth is associated with 'strength'. Soin this casewe can conclude that the relation direction is expressed by the estimate ? But what about exploring 'diameter' effect on 'strength' per 'machine'. I wanna have conclusion of this type : for 'diameter' (inferior to the mean) associated with machine A (and b and c), we have increasing (or not) in 'strength'?

Comment: It is your MODEL that has the limitation you describe. To have different slopes, you need to include the interaction of machine and diameter. I think it would be helpful to find someone (e.g. a statistics grad student) to talk you through this personally. The modeling step s crucial - you have to get that right before doing any post hoc analyses.